# Sonar server can not be reached. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to run a maven build for sonarqube:

> mvn clean install sonar:sonar
>   -Dsonar.host.url=http://ourserver.lan:9000 -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://ourserver.lan:9092/sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.username=admin -Dsonar.jdbc.password=xxx

But I am getting the error:

> Sonar server can not be reached. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url': http://ourserver.lan:9000

The server itself is reachable, I get to the main page of sonarqube if I enter the URL in the browser.

What I configured:

- General - Server base URL - Set to "http://ourserver.lan"
- Security - Allow users to sign up online

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube 5.1 is not compatible with Maven 2.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that.

Comment: If you must use Maven 2 to build the project (e.g., because of some old plugin that doesn't work in Maven 3) you can run `mvn sonar:sonar` as a separate command using Maven 3 after building with Maven 2.